# Wget recognizes some part of my URL address as a syntax error

Tags: html, syntax, save, wget

I am quite new with `wget` and I have done my research on Google but I found no clue.

I need to save a single HTML file of a webpage:

```
wget yahoo.com -O test.html
```

and it works, but, when I try to be more specific:

```
wget http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search&p=food+delicious -O test.html
```

here comes the problem, `wget` recognizes `&p=food+delicious` as a syntax, it says: `'p' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

How can I solve this problem? I really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: what u want to do? whats the purpose?

Comment: i want a search engine to count how many hits does my keyword have,

so i simply make a URL that contains my keyword in it,

but the problem comes as wget recognize soome part of my URL address as a syntax error

Answer (score 16):

The `&` has a special meaning in the shell. Escape it with `\` or put the url in quotes to avoid this problem.

```
wget http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search\&p=food+delicious -O test.html
```

or

```
wget "http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search&p=food+delicious" -O test.html
```

In many Unix shells, putting an `&` after a command causes it to be [executed in the background](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/).

Comment: To clarify, this has nothing to do with wget. The special meaning of `&` is interpreted (by bash, sh, or whatever) before it gets to wget.

Comment: actually i am running wget on windows,
and i have tried your suggestions, but none of the works,

when i tried this : wget http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search\&p=food+delicious -O test.html

it gives the same error message,

when i tried this: wget "http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search&p=food+delicious" -O test.html

it goes: error 404: Not Found

Comment: The 404 you get is a problem with the url (notice the `/404handler?...` part?) . `http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=food+delicious` seems to work better, but you should really research how interaction with Yahoo search should be scripted.

Comment: Single quotes did not work for me but scape the & with \ made the affair for me

Comment: the second option is awesome :D

Answer (score 9):

Wrap your URL in single quotes to avoid this issue.

i.e.

```
wget 'http://search.yahoo.com/404handler?src=search&p=food+delicious' -O test.html
```

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but it doesn't work,
it goes: 'error 404: Not found'

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a jubyter notebook, maybe check if you have downloaded

```
pip install wget
```

before warping from URL