# How can I copy image from server to local using NodeJS or Commandline

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'm using nodeJS and I need to save images hosted at Facebook into my local server. currently I am executing command line using exec to get this working. something like

```
wget https://example.com/image.jpg -O ic_launcher.jpg
```

it works, but when I have a complex url like

```
wget https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20206198_1998942567005064_567078929_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=e92a33eb810eeb12f199a567cdaf035d&oe=5972D7E3 -O ic_launcher.jpg
```

it doesn't work because of the & that is on the url, how can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to put the url between double quotation. Something like
wget "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20206198_1998942567005064_567078929_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=e92a33eb810eeb12f199a567cdaf035d&oe=5972D7E3" -O ic_launcher.jpg

Comment: I believe you can use escape. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625583/4168649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added "" to the url it worked, neat little trick but didn't know it. Well now I do.