# Can't find commands at the end

Tags: sql, linux, bash, sql-injection

I tried an SQL injection on a private VM and used sqlmap. Somehow the command:

```
sqlmap -u http://link/index.html?page=blog&title=Blog&id=5 --random-agent
```

Gives me:

```
[2] 16
[3] 17
-bash: --random-agent: command not found
[1]   Done                    sqlmap -u http://link/index.html?page=blog
[3]+  Done                    title=Blog
```

But putting --random-agent first and -u second works somehow but then sqlmap asks me:

```
[20:29:29] [CRITICAL] heuristics detected that the target is protected by some kind of WAF/IPS/IDS
do you want sqlmap to try to detect backend WAF/IPS/IDS? [y/N] y
-bash: y: command not found

[1]+  Stopped                 sqlmap --random-agent -u http://link/index.html?page=blog
[2]   Done                    title=Blog
```

Why can't I enter y and why do I have to put options in front of -u

Update, upgrade, and reinstall didn't work by the way,.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339469/how-to-include-an-character-in-a-bash-curl-statement

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100099/why-is-curl-truncating-this-query-string Same cause in both cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wget recognizes some part of my URL address as a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5625552/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the address in quotes:

```
sqlmap -u "http://link/index.html?page=blog&title=Blog&id=5" --random-agent
```

Else [you'd start one process per ampersand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86253/304256) in the background.